# Button action not called in custom CollectionView Cell in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, button, action, collectionview

I created a custom collection view cell and added a button programmatically.But the button action is not getting called.Below is the code

```
//Button Creation
public var checkBoxButton: UIButton = {
    let checkBoxButton = UIButton()
    checkBoxButton.backgroundColor = .black
    checkBoxButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "CheckBox_Normal"), for: .normal)
    checkBoxButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "CheckBox_Selected"), for: .selected)
    checkBoxButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    checkBoxButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(paymentModeSelected(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    return checkBoxButton
}()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    contentView.addSubview(checkBoxButton)
}

@objc private func paymentModeSelected(_ sender:UIButton!){
    sender.isSelected = true

   print('Button clicked')
}
```

But it is called when the button action is written in init
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

```
    contentView.addSubview(checkBoxButton)
    checkBoxButton.addTarget(self, action: 
       #selector(paymentModeSelected(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)


}
```

Comment: Have you tried making it a `lazy var`?

Comment: Thanks!! This helped me.Can you explain the difference why it did not work originally.I am new to swift.The reason would help me in avoiding this mistake in future

Comment: When I tried with lazy var only for the first click the action is called.Second time when I click the issue is still the same

Comment: I did a mistake.I added                                                                        
  override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        checkBoxButton.removeTarget(nil, action: nil, for: .allEvents)
    }.Because of this the button action is not called second time

Comment: `lazy vars` are not initialised with the controller. Instead they are initialised when they are accessed. In your case, without the lazy var, you were assigning a target (which might not have been processed yet) to the button when the class initialised. However, when you used lazy var, it just declared the button instead of initialising it. Hope this clarifies the issue for you